# How to remove close button (x) border from google maps info window pop up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Is there any way to get rid of the border around the close (x) button on google maps info windows? 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YwvO.png).

I have tried everything I can find on stack overflow.

This doesn't work:

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw + div {
display: none; /* <-- this will generally work on the fly. */
visibility: hidden; /* this 2 lines below are just for hard hiding. :) */
opacity: 0;}
```

Nor does this:

```
.gm-style-iw + div {display: none;}
```

Maybe replacing the image in the info window would be an alternate solution? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you using a framework or changing styles with JS? At the moment this seems to be a CSS/styling question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Infowindow documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows):

> The InfoWindow class does not offer customization.

I would suggest that you use the [customized popup](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup) as this doesn't contain the close button in the creation of the popup.

```
function Popup(position, content) {
this.position = position;

content.classList.add('popup-bubble');

// This zero-height div is positioned at the bottom of the bubble.
var bubbleAnchor = document.createElement('div');
bubbleAnchor.classList.add('popup-bubble-anchor');
bubbleAnchor.appendChild(content);

// This zero-height div is positioned at the bottom of the tip.
this.containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
this.containerDiv.classList.add('popup-container');
this.containerDiv.appendChild(bubbleAnchor);

// Optionally stop clicks, etc., from bubbling up to the map.
google.maps.OverlayView.preventMapHitsAndGesturesFrom(this.containerDiv);
}
```

You may see the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/srxgeuy9/)

Note: Please don't forget to add your API key in the sample.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I'll try this!

Answer (score 8):

In my case was the button focus, solved like this:

```
.gm-style-iw button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean `.gm-style-iw button:focus` (no **,**). Solved it for me without having to rewrite existing JS

Answer (score 1):

I just got rid of the "x" entirely by using the following code:

```
.gm-style-iw button {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now there looks to be quite a bit of padding around the x in the screenshot. I'd inspect the element and see if there are any styles from parent elements or related classes overriding changes you make on its border or outline. If not, have you tried the following selectors?

`outline: none`

`border-radius: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in side of InfoWindow.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white; z-index: 2;"></div>
```